# JavaScript as a robust hack for inline-block de-spacing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm keen to use `inline-block` extensively as part of a fluid, responsive design, rather than lots of `float: left` and clearfix hacks. Until HTML5/CSS3 provides a way of ignoring spaces, and everyone upgrades to browsers that support this new feature (i.e. maybe five years if we're lucky) there will always be problems making this kind of layout.

There are a lot of hacks you can use to avoid the problem of browsers rendering space between inline-blocks: write code without spaces, comment out the spaces, some horrible font size hacks, etc. but None of them feel that great to me. I'm thinking instead of adding some inline JavaScript to the very bottom of my `body` tag:

`document.getElementById('base').innerHTML = document.getElementById('base').innerHTML.replace(/\x3e\s+\x3c/g, '\x3e\x3c');`

Essentially a post-hoc implementation of the "write code without spaces" implementation. I've tested it on a range of browsers and they all seem pretty happy with it - my question is: is there some grave hidden danger that I'm not seeing?

I've created a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardc/wdz5t/

Obviously there may be occasions when I actually want space - I can deal with those easily. And there might be issues with JavaScript bindings falling off - I'm pretty sure all my jQuery bindings will always attach after a script at the bottom of the body runs, and even if there's an issue, `.on()` should provide an easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to your question, there isn't any real downside to what you are attempting, save for the fact that your page will take longer to render — because the page will already have started being evaluated — plus it will depend on the speed and existence of JavaScript. One thing you could do to avoid doing things twice is to wrap your page content using `nosript`.

```
<body>
<noscript id="base">
  <!-- rest of your content goes here //-->
</noscript>
<script>
  document.write(
    String(document.getElementById('base').innerHTML)
      /// IE annoyingly entity encodes noscript content, so reverse
      .replace(/&gt;/gi,'>')
      .replace(/&lt;/gi,'<')
      /// deploy your space removal however you like
      .replace(/\x3e\s+\x3c/g, '\x3e\x3c')
  );
</script>
</body>
```

The above would mean non-js browsers would just get on rendering the page, and js-enabled browsers wouldn't render anything until executing the `document.write`.

I can't recommend the above however, or using `display: inline-block` for what you are trying to do...

Basically because I don't find using floats much of a problem — that's probably because I do find browsers rendering unexpected whitespace a tad annoying — to me, rather than any of this trickery, it's far far easier and more stable and supported to do the following:

```
<ul class="overflow-fix">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Where the css would be:

```
.overflow-fix {
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
}
```

Over my years of web development, I have only ever come across one situation where I needed to overflow content from within a float... it was only in that case that I needed to use the rather awkward "clear fix". I also seem to have avoided the need for centering any inline content, that might just have been luck however.

+1 to James Donnelly — as he indeed has given an exact and correct answer in keeping with `inline-block`. However, to me, it feels that anything which leads you to mess around with the markup layout, should be avoided until it is a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

The pure HTML/CSS methods you've mentioned in your post work fine without requiring your website's users to have scripts enabled.

Here is a [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/hmlqF) from [this CSS-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) which shows all of the methods which don't *feel great* for you in action.

Your JavaScript is a good enough solution, by the look of things (provided you're not wanting to support IE7), but you may also want to apply some of the above methods as a fall back.